# Transpose only one column in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet like this:

[image]

I want it to have two columns: `in` and `out` with the corresponding values:

[image]

I'm able to do so using sorting and copy-pasting, but as the data gets more complicated this way gets more complicated, and less safe, as well. Maybe there is a simple, correct way for such a transformation?

Comment: +Valentin, On second thought, it might be better to use `SUM(C)`. If you agree, I will edit my post.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra yeah - I used SUM on my own :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) to obtain the result you want.

### Formula

```
=QUERY(A1:C6, "SELECT A, MAX(C) GROUP BY A PIVOT B")
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[Transpose only one column in Google Spreadsheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yafn9UCrPzI79ivaRiV-01OO2i-3JU9Fmo4uet2zMII/edit?usp=sharing)**