# How to count wins, losses and ties based on multiple conditions

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm very new to Google Sheets.

I have a sheet where I record the outcomes of games played.

- Each row represents a single game
- Column A, `Map`, stores the name of the map that was played.
- Column D, `Result`, contains either **Win**, **Loss**, or **Tie**.

### Sample Data

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Map** |  |  | **Result** |
| **2** | Mirage | 10/13 | 15/3/14 | Loss |
| **3** | Nuke | 113:7 | 18/1/13 | Win |
| **4** | Inferno | 13:10 | 18/3/17 | Win |
| **5** | Mirage | 116:12 | 13/3/23 | Win |
| **6** | Mirage | 115:15 | 13/5/22 | Tie |
| **7** | Inferno | 1:9 | 23/8/22 | Loss |
| **8** | Vertigo | 17:13 | 6/1/9 | Loss |
| **9** | Nuke | 113:7 | 15/6/16 | Win |
| **10** | Inferno | 13:10 | 9/6/18 | Win |
| **11** | Vertigo | 116:14 | 24/21/5 | Win |
| **12** | Overpass | 13:11 | 18/14/2 | Win |
| **13** | Mirage | 8:13 | 14/15/2 | Loss |

### Count by Result

I created a formula using COUNTIF that returns the total count based on the `Result` (outcome) entered in the cell above it.

```
=COUNTIF($D$2:$D$13, G$1)
```

- formula is in `G2` and was also copied to `H2` and `I2`

|  | F | G | H | I |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **MAP** | **WIN** | **LOSS** | **TIE** |
| **2** | All | 7 | 4 | 1 |

## Count by Result and by Map

Similar to my formula above, I'd like to return the total count but by `Map`.  For example, if the `Map` is **Mirage** then the total **wins**, **losses**, and **ties** across all games played on the **Mirage** map only.

How can I do that?

##### Desired Results

|  | F | G | H | I |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **MAP** | **WIN** | **LOSS** | **TIE** |
| **2** | All | 7 | 4 | 1 |
| **3** |  |  |  |  |
| **4** | Mirage | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| **5** | Overpass | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| **6** | Vertigo | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| **7** | Inferno | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| **8** | Nuke | 2 | 0 | 0 |

<sub>**Sample Data**</sub>
[image: A picture of a small part of my sheet, here you can see the different maps in bold colors and the wins, losses and ties that are connected to each map]

<sub>**Sample Results**</sub>
[image: This is how I am going to showcase the wins, losses and ties in total for each map in the game]

Comment: One of the concepts that you might need to learn is [data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure), and more specifically, [simple table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_(information)#Simple_table). While spreadsheets are very flexible, I suggest you ensure that your data is entered in the form of *simple table*. The top row should have column headers, which should be unique. Once you have set your data this way, you might use the pivot table and the QUERY function to achieve the result efficiently. The second image shows a double-entry table with column and row headers.

Comment: In this case, the headers are grouping data and the intersection shows an aggregation calculation. This is frequently referred to as "pivot", hence the name of the tool "pivot table".

Comment: Related: [Can someone help me with this google sheets group by query?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/137058/88163), [Transpose only one column in Google Spreadsheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/95457/88163)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## QUERY Approach

<sup>***** Credit to Rubén</sup>

```
=QUERY(A:D, 
   "Select A, count(A)
   where D is not NULL
   group by A pivot D", 1 )
```

## QUERY w/ Total Row

```
=LET(q,QUERY(A:D, 
   "Select A, count(A)
    where D is not NULL
    group by A pivot D", 1),  
   {q; "", "", "", "";
   "TOTAL", 
   INDEX(QUERY("Select
     sum(Col2), sum(Col3),
     sum(Col4)",1),2)})
```

## COUNTIFS Approach

Use [COUNTIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550?hl=en) to allow an additional condition.

In `G4` adapt your existing formula with an additional condition that `Map` matches the value in `F4` as  follows:

```
=COUNTIFS($D$2:$D, G$1,
          $A$2:$A, $F4)
```

- you can copy this formula to the rest of the cells that need it (eg. `G4:I8`).

## Multi-Row Formula

- Places the **Basic Formula** inside [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) so the formula in `G4` will fill all the necessary rows below it without copying it down.
- Works on a single column so needs to be copied to `H4` and `I4`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   COUNTIFS(
     $D2:$D, G1,
     $A2:$A, $F4:$F8))
```

## Multi-Column & Row

- A single formula populates all the counts in `G4:I8` (both columns and rows).
- [BYCOL](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12571032?hl=en) passes each of the values in `G1:I1` one-by-one into a [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en) that stores the current one in the variable `_col`
- [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en)'s formula is based on the  **Multi-Row Formula** but the variable `c` replaces the cell references to `G1`or `H1` or `I1`.

```
=BYCOL(G1:I1, LAMBDA(c,
   ARRAYFORMULA(
     COUNTIFS(
       D2:D, c,
       A2:A, F4:F8))))
```

## All Labels & Values

- Single formula in `F1` that creates all headings, lookup values, and result counts.

```
=LET(maps,A2:A, wlt,D2:D,
  umaps,UNIQUE(TOCOL(maps, 1)), 
  uwlt,{"WIN", "LOSS", "TIE"},
  ttls,BYCOL(uwlt, LAMBDA(u,
    ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIFS(
      wlt, u, maps, umaps)))), 
  all,{"All", BYCOL(ttls,
    LAMBDA(t, SUM(t)))},
  IFERROR(VSTACK(
    {"MAP", uwlt}, all,, 
    SORT({umaps, ttls}))))
```

---

## Function Support

[ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) [BYCOL](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12571032?hl=en) [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en) [COUNTIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550?hl=en) [IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en) [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en) [LET](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535?hl=en) [SORT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150?hl=en) [TOCOL](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13187258?hl=en) [UNIQUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10522653?hl=en) [VSTACK](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13191461?hl=en)